# JSON Schema enforce a property to be a reference to an ID

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm not sure there's even a way to do this. But what I want to achieve is the following: I want a JSON schema to enforce that a certain object contains a property that is a reference to an id of another object.

Here's a simplified example:

```json
{
  "objectA": {
    "@id": "obj-a-001",
    "@ref": "obj-b-001"
  },
  "objectB": {
    "@id": "obj-b-001",
    "props": "whatever"
  }
}
```

As you can see, `objectA` has a reference to the `@id` of `objectB`.
Now I'd like to be able to enforce this with a json schema: It should be valid if there is an object that has the ID that is used in the reference; but it should give an error if there isn't.
So, basically what XML can do with `id` and `ref`.
(I don't mind how exactly this is represented in json: could just as well be `id` or `$id` or something like this.)

Is this even possible in json schema? and if so, how? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: You cannot do referential integrity checks with JSON Schema.

Comment: Too bad. But thanks!